# How to get form input using forms.Form into a postgres database?

Tags: django, forms, postgresql

Here is my code:

My forms.py looks like:

```
from django import forms


class SimpleForm(forms.Form):
    website = forms.URLField(required=True,
                             widget=forms.TextInput(
                             attrs={'placeholder': "http://www.example.com"}))
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(
                            attrs={'type': 'email',
                                   'placeholder': "john.doe@example.com"
                                  }))
```

My views.py looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template import loader

from .forms import SimpleForm


def simple_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SimpleForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            website = form.cleaned_data['website']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']

            return render(request, 'some_page.html')
    else:
        form = SimpleForm()

    return render(request, 'some_other_page.html', {'form': form})
```

As for my HTML form, it looks like the following below:

```
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="some-class">
    <label for="website">Enter Your Site:</label>
    <!-- <input type="text" id="website" placeholder="http://www.example.com" name="website" /> -->
    {{ form.website }}
    <label for="email">Enter Your Email:</label>
    <!-- <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="john.doe@example.com" name="website" /> -->
    {{ form.email }}
  </div>
  <div class="some-other-class">
      <div class="another-class">
        <button name="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My question is, how do I get the input for this form into a table in my postgres database?

Comment: Do you have a model? If so, why don't you use a model form? And if not, how are you expecting the data to go into the db?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I just followed this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/

Comment: Well that's just one part of it. Rather than reading a single page of the documentation, you should follow the tutorial.

Comment: @DanielRoseman what tutorial?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) instead of a form and turn your form into a Model:

```
class SimpleModel(models.Model):
    website = models.URLField(
        required=True, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': "http://www.example.com"}))
    email = models.EmailField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'email', 'placeholder': "john.doe@example.com"}))

class SimpleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SimpleModel
        fields = ['website', 'email']
```

Follow the link and look at the docs, you can make it very abstract, Django can handle most things for u.

When saving you can do a `form.save()` as seen [here](http://%20https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method.)

It is wise to first check the form by doing `form.is_valid()`

Example view:

```
def simple_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SimpleForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'some_page.html')
    form = SimpleForm()
    return render(request, 'some_other_page.html', {'form': form})
```

**You can also follow [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/) to get to know the Django basics**
Sounds like you could use the basics ;)

Comment: How to i `obj.save()` this if my views have a `website` and `email` under the conditional? do I do `form.save()` anyway?